# Lambda's from glmnet (R) used in online SGD

Tags: r, glmnet, gradient-descent

I'm using `cv.glmnet` from `glmnet` package (in `R`). In the outcome I get a vector of `lambda`'s (regularization parameter). I would like to use it in the online SGD algorithm. Is there a way of doing so and how?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

I am wondering how can I compare results (in the terms of a model's coefficients and regularization output parameter) in generalized linear model with l1 regularization and binomial distribution (logistic link function) that was calculated once in offline using cv.glmnet function from R package that I think uses Raphson-Newton estimation algorithm WITH online evaluating model of the same type but where the estimates are re-calculated after every new observation using stochastic-gradient-descent algorithm ( classic, type I ).